# Html Find and hide text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some html like this :

```
<p>a. Is there a skin and/or scar condition?
    <br>
    <input id="ucWSDBQ_CheckBox3" type="checkbox" name="ucWSDBQ$CheckBox3">
    <label for="ucWSDBQ_CheckBox3"></label>Yes&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;
    <input id="ucWSDBQ_CheckBox5" type="checkbox" name="ucWSDBQ$CheckBox5">
    <label for="ucWSDBQ_CheckBox5"></label>No
    <br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; If yes, check all that apply and complete the corresponding DBQ(s):
    <br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
    <input id="ucWSDBQ_CheckBox6" type="checkbox" name="ucWSDBQ$CheckBox6">
    <label for="ucWSDBQ_CheckBox6"></label>&nbsp;<b>Skin Diseases DBQ<br> </b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;
    <input id="ucWSDBQ_CheckBox7" type="checkbox" name="ucWSDBQ$CheckBox7">
    <label for="ucWSDBQ_CheckBox7"></label> <b>&nbsp;Scars DBQ</b>
</p>
```

I want to hide the text **If yes, check all that apply and complete the corresponding**  when user clicks No, and show the text when user clicks Yes. I have tried different things but didn't work.
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrashid/yUu6q/9/)

Comment: Should the Yes/No checkboxes not be radio buttons? At the moment you can select both Yes *and* No.

Comment: I have a script to uncheck another if one is checked.

Comment: Might want to stick content for the label tabs inside the label tags.

Comment: `I have a script to uncheck another if one is checked.` Just use radio buttons. That script is pointless as the browser takes care of it for you.

Comment: I am not allowed to change any html, can you hide the text only for No?

Comment: Show the script you have so far. Also, it's not possible to hide just that one line without changing the HTML, or at least the DOM tree. Otherwise, you'd be hiding much more text.

Comment: Why aren't you allowed to change the html? It's atrocious (and I'm being as kind as I possibly can be about it), unnecessarily complicated, inappropriately wrapped and using unnecessary JavaScript to compensate for its flaws.

Comment: Ok, i think it is not possible with current state of html, Right??

Comment: Exactly. What you are trying to hide or show should be be in a container element of its own, like in jollelj's fiddle. It's impossible to hide part of an element! So if your HTML is cast in stone, you'll need a LOT of scriptage to make it work. (Removing elements and fragments of text nodes from the DOM tree, putting them back in another place, restoring all the event handlers etc. Even if we all know that it could be done much easily and more straightforward, and that this HTML is already in dire need of being put down and replaced with something better.)

Answer (score 0):

Look at this fiddle and see if it's what you're after.

```
$('form').on('click', function() {
    if($('#ucWSDBQ_CheckBox3').is(':checked')) {
        $('.hidden').css('display', 'block');
    } else {
        $('.hidden').css('display', 'none');
    }
});
```

I've added a form and a wrapper-div to your HTML.

http://jsfiddle.net/yUu6q/10/

Comment: I can't change the html, we have to solve this using current html.

Comment: when you click on YES text is shown but when you click on NO it should be hidden...

Answer (score 0):

Handle the onClick event of the checkbox. In that you will have to write code for whatever you want to achieve